# select from two tables using JPQL

Tags: java, orm, jpa-2.0, jpql, openjpa

I'm using `JPQL` to retrieve data. I can get data using the statement

```
List persons = null;
persons = em.createQuery("select p.albumName from PhotoAlbum p , Roleuser r 
where r = p.userId and r.userID = 1");
```

Now I can get the album names using this:

```
int i=0;
for (i=0;i<persons.size(); i++)
{   
     System.out.println("Testing n "+ i +" " +  persons.get(0));
}
```

Now I want to get the album name and the roleuser's row named `firstname`

I'm using the query

```
persons = em.createQuery("select r.firstName , p.albumName from PhotoAlbum p ,   
Roleuser r where r = p.userId and r.userID = 1").getResultList();
```

Now how do I get the rows firstname and albumname as the persons.get(0) is returning a object

by running the code :

```
 for (i=0;i<persons.size(); i++)
    {
        //r = (Roleuser) persons.get(i);
        System.out.println("Testing n "+ i +" " + persons.get(i));
    }
```

I'm getting this:

```
Testing n 0 [Ljava.lang.Object;@4edb4077
INFO: Testing n 1 [Ljava.lang.Object;@1c656d13
INFO: Testing n 2 [Ljava.lang.Object;@46dc08f5
INFO: Testing n 3 [Ljava.lang.Object;@654c0a43
```

How do I map the `persons.get(0)` and get the `firstname` and `albumname`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now how do get the rows firstname and albumname as the persons.get(0) is returning a object

Queries with multiple *select_expressions* in the SELECT clause return an `Object[]` (or a `List` of `Object[]`). From the JPA specification:

> #### 4.8.1 Result Type of the SELECT Clause
>
> The type of the query result specified
>   by the SELECT clause of a query is an
>   entity abstract schema type, a
>   state-field type, the result of an
>   aggregate function, the result of a
>   construction operation, or some
>   sequence of these.
>
> The result type of the SELECT clause
>   is defined by the the result types of
>   the *select_expressions* contained in
>   it. When multiple
>   *select_expressions* are used in the SELECT clause, the result of the query
>   is of type `Object[]`, and the
>   elements in this result correspond in
>   order to the order of their
>   specification in the SELECT clause and
>   in type to the result types of each of
>   the *select_expressions*.

So in your case, you probably want something like this:

```
for (i=0;i<persons.size(); i++) {
    //r = (Roleuser) persons.get(i);
    System.out.println("Testing n " + i + " " + persons.get(i)[0] + ", " + 
        persons.get(i)[1]);
}
```

Note that specifying an inner join by the use of a cartesian product in the FROM clause and a join condition in the WHERE clause is less typical than specifying an explicit join over entity relationships (using the `[LEFT [OUTER] | INNER ] JOIN` syntax). See the whole section **4.4.5 Joins** in the specification.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - Section 4.8.1 "Result Type of the SELECT Clause"
  - Section 4.8.2 "Constructor Expressions in the SELECT Clause"
  - Section 4.4.5 "Joins"

Comment: any link for jpql specifications and how tos

Comment: any how can we use stored procedures of the db, in my case mysql as without stored procedures i think JPA is slower performer than db's stored procedures.